# Is there a keyboard shortcut to show the function parameters information popup?

Tags: keyboard

Is there a keyboard shortcut to force this popup menu to appear, as I am typing the parameters? My reason for wanting it to show is so that I can remember what the parameters to the function are.

[image]

I know that once you paste the definition, Mathematica will show this:
[image]

It's very useful but sometimes if there's a lot of parameters, it's easy to forget for example what x1,y1,z1 actually is. It would be nice to press a keyboard shortcut and see it inline, instead of having to open the documentation.

Comment: Command-Shift-K on my mac brings up the dialog. But you're asking how to make it appear "as [you type] the parameters". So, you want some sort of continuous action? That wouldn't be a shortcut. I'm confused.

Comment: Windows 10: If you type  the argument brackets a popup is shown where you can choose either the help or a short description of the expected input. The same is shown if you click inside the brackets.

Comment: @lericr Ctrl-Shift-K is what I was looking for! Feel free to post as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Mac, it's Command-Shift-K.

(making this a community post so others can answer for their platform)